# Conversion from ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to convert following string from ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8 but not converting properly.

```
$content = 'Mieszkanie dla Młodych. Od dziś kredyty z pomocą państwa';
$xy = utf8_encode($content);
echo $xy;
Output - Mieszkanie dla MÅodych. Od dziÅ kredyty z pomocÄ paÅstwa
```

i am not able to understand what is going wrong.
Any one expert in conversion could you please share some idea.

I may be missing something here.

Thank you

Update :-  i tried iconv but that also not working

```
iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8", $content);
iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $content);
iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $content);

Output - Mieszkanie dla MĹodych. Od dziĹ kredyty z pomocÄ paĹstwa
```

Comment: Use [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [mb_convert_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php); utf8_encode() is specifically for ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Comment: Thank you @MarkBaker i tried iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2//TRANSLIT", $content); but that also does not work. Does something different.

Comment: Reverse the order of your charsets: 1st argument is the input (from) charset, 2nd is the output (to) charset

Comment: You are sure that your input string (`$content`) is encoded in ISO-8859-2?

Answer (score 1):

Use [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for conversion.It provides `Original` , `TRANSLIT`, `Plain` , `IGNORE`.I guess you need to try all to get your desired output

```
<?php
$text = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("ISO-8859-2//TRANSLIT", "UTF-8" ,$text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("ISO-8859-2//IGNORE","UTF-8",  $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("ISO-8859-2","UTF-8",  $text), PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Comment: We are talking about ISO-8859-2, I guess.

Comment: Hi Freak - i tried that as well but no luck.. Yes i am sure it is ISO-8859-2 Estshy.  Thank you in advance... No idea what is going wrong... For more info this is RSS - www.money.pl/rss/main.xml  which is in ISO-8859-2 format.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely UTF-8. XML files are UTF by default unless there's a `Content-Type:...charset` or `<?xml encoding` stating otherwise. That RSS file has neither.

Comment: Hi Estshy/bobince - if you do view source you will see <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?> there on that file. Thank you.

Comment: That's odd, I have now seen it both with and without the 8859-2 prolog. Not sure what makes it vary. When there *is* the encoding parameter,  `iconv("ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8", $content)` will be the right thing to do to convert to UTF-8. However by far the best approach would be to use a proper XML parser, which would cope with the encoding prolog automatically.